# Rails: ActiveAdmin custom filter returning errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, meta-search

I am trying to setup a custom filter with my `ActiveAdmin` installation and it is returning some errors.

User Model:

```
class User < AR::Base
   has_many :gpas

   def current_gpa
    return nil if gpas.blank?
    @current_gpa ||= (gpas.where(year: classification).first || gpas.order("updated_at DESC").first)
   end

end
```

ActiveAdmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Athlete do
  filter :current_gpa_value, as: :string
end
```

The error I get is:
`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method current_gpa_value_contains for #<MetaSearch::Searches::User:0x007f982df8fd28>)`

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin uses metasearch for filters. Check out this [example](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search#accessing-custom-search-methods-and-named-scopes) of how to set up a custom search method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use scopes:

```
class User < AR::Base
   has_many :gpas
scope :current_gpa, where(....)



ActiveAdmin.register Athlete do
  scope :current_gpa
end
```